# Dojox Json Query expressions

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am using Dojox to get an array of objects back that meet an expression, I recently changed my service and now it returns more complicated JSON property banes and my query has stopped working. I think I can place a wild card `[*]`operator to the start of my query string.

**Old JSON**

```
[
    {
      "attributes": [{
          "Type": 1,
          "User": "Dave",
          "Location": "England"
      }]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [{
          "Type": 1,
          "User": "Paul",
          "Location": "England"
      }]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [{
          "Type": 2,
          "User": "James",
          "Location": "England"
      }]
    }
]
```

**Old query string**

```
var jam = dojox.json.query(“[?attributes.Type='0'”, data);
```

This used to work fine but since the JSON has changed the query isn't working

**New JSON**

```
[
    {
      "attributes": [{
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Type: 1,
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.User: "Dave",
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Location: "England",
      }]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [{
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Type: 1,
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.User: "Paul",
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Location: "England",
      }]
    },
    {
      "attributes": [{
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Type: 2,
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.User: "Steve",
              somevalue."sometingelse".username.Location: "England",
      }]
    }
]
```

I have tried with a few variations of a similar query with no success

```
var jam = dojox.json.query(“[?attributes.*Type='0'”, data);
var jam = dojox.json.query(“[?attributes][*Type='0']”, data);
```

Happy to give further details, thank you in advance.

Comment: `somevalue."sometingelse".username.Type: 1` it's php ? where did you write this ? (because actually your new JSON is not a JSON)

Comment: @SteevePitis It's valid(ish) JSON and it is returned by an ArgGis server not PHP http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver

Comment: The downvote is not mine ;) Is it the returned JSON ?

Comment: @SteevePitis yeah essentially `somevalue."sometingelse".username.Type` comes out as a full field name.

Comment: @jonathan-newton  Its not `somevalue.sometingelse.username.Type`, it is a full schema name and layer name included. You can ask you GIS Administrator to remove them from the service. It can be maintained as same as before.

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting so OP can clarify or improve his question. Thanks!

Comment: @TKambi essentially a dodgy join we replaced it with a view and set the field names, although it wasn't a Dojox Json Query answer I would be happy to take this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially a dodgy join we replaced it with a view and set the field names. Another fix was to rename all the layers in the MXD and republished the ArcGIS service.

`var jam = dojox.json.query(“[?attributes.Type='0'”, data);`

Would work fine after that.